# Strange error when try to make $push into collection of generic objects on MongoDb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, generics

I use MongoDB driver with TypeScript. I have two generic classes - `Container<T>` and `Item<T>`. `Container` has a field `item` of `Item<T>` and array `items` of `Item<T>`. When I try to update `Container`'s field with `$set`, everything is OK. But when I try to update `Container`'s array with `$push`, compiler produces an error:

```
Type '{ items: { field: T; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PushOperator<Container<T>>'.
  Type '{ items: { field: T; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [key in KeysOfAType<Container<T>, readonly any[]>]?: Flatten<Container<T>[key]> | ArrayOperator<Flatten<Container<T>[key]>[]> | undefined; }'.ts(2322)
```

My code:

```
import { Collection } from 'mongodb';

export type Item<T> = {
  field: T;
};

export type Container<T> = {
  field: T;
  item: Item<T>;
  items: Item<T>[];
};

export const work = async <T>(containers: Collection<Container<T>>, container: Container<T>) => {
  const item = { field: container.field };
  await containers.updateOne(
    {},
    {
      $set: { item }, // OK
      $push: { items: item }, // Compiler error!
    },
  );
};
```

Comment: Does quoting the field name make any difference?